# why is this not getting me the value of the input as the location?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a weather app and I want that when the user inputs something, it should make the location change for the one that it was inputted. But when i try to work this code it doesn't work:

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form-input">
        <input id="city-weather"/>
        <button type="button" name="button">Search</button>
    </form>
  </body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```js
function searchInput() {
  var search = document.getElementById('form-input')

  search.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    var id = document.getElementById("city-weather").value
  })
}

async function getWeather() {
  var location = searchInput()
  
  try {
      let response = await 
      fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${location}&appid=7d93c09c5bd7fccd41b0f335e310a15b`)
       let user = await response.json()

       console.log(user)
  } catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Comment: Who calls `getWeather()` ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
document.getElementById('form-input').addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cityId = document.getElementById("city-weather").value;
    getWeather(id);
  })
}

async function getWeather(cityId) {
  try {
    let response = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityId}&appid=7d93c09c5bd7fccd41b0f335e310a15b`)
    let user = await response.json()

    console.log(user)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

#### Explanation:

Your code had few mistakes:

- No one was calling the function `getWeather`
- You assumed `searchInput` would return a value while it would haven't

The attached code instead listens to the submission event on the global scope, and then calls the `getWeather` function giving it the `cityId`.

Comment: `document.getElementById('form-input').search.addEventListener` will throw an exception because `search` is undefined

Comment: @Quentin Fixed, Thanks.